# vba to send email based on specific value and due date

Tags: excel, vba

Hi there i currently have below code whereby it will send email every time it meets target of 16, 64 and 125 however is it possible along with dates

for example only send email if value of 16 is within 3 months, 64 if it is within 6 month and 125 over one year period.

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim NotSentMsg As String
Dim MyMsg As String
Dim SentMsg As String

On Error GoTo errHandler:
Sheet3.Unprotect Password:="1234"

NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
SentMsg = "Sent"

With Me.Range("B6")
    If Not IsNumeric(.Value) Then
        MyMsg = "Not numeric"
    Else
        If .Value = 16 <= Now() - 90 Or .Value = 64 <= Now() - 190 Or .Value > 125 <= Now() - 365 Then
            MyMsg = SentMsg
            If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                Call Mail_Outlook_With_Signature_Html_2
                MsgBox "Email has been sent", vbInformation
            End If
        Else
            MyMsg = NotSentMsg
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End With

Application.EnableEvents = True
Sheet3.Protect Password:="1234"
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:
MsgBox "An Error has Occurred  " & vbCrLf & _
       "The error number is:  " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
       Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Please Contact Admin"

End Sub
```

Comment: How is "16" within 3 months?  Where is the date which is supposed to be measured against?

Comment: Hi Basically target of 16, 64 or 125, we have policy if person is sick  and hit target of 16 within 3 months of 64 over 6 month or 125 over a year then action need to be taken here it is complicated for vba to work out. how about 3 different cells has back dated dates and then my target cell calculate from todays dates? is something can be this way?

Comment: something along with this line: If .Value > 15 And .Value < 25 And Now() < ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2021").Range("B8") Then, and same for 64 and 125?

Comment: Use parentheses to group your tests  - `If (A and B and C) or (D and E and F) or (H and I and J) Then`  It would help to explain in detail where the dates are coming from for each test.  From the same dell in each case or ?

Comment: Hi Tim sorry would you kindly help me coding and where do i write sheet as am not an expert on vba. many thanks

Comment: I can help with the code if you can clarify the question.  What are the 3 exact criteria for the cell's value (you have both exact values and ranges in your Q / comments) and where are the 3 cells which hold the dates to be checked against?

Comment: Hi Tim Thanks, basically i have staff yearly diary in a range from B10:AF32. you add "S" in any range cells it will calculate all the S in to the cell "B6". S stands for Sickness of individual had in a whole year, so i have got the code to send an email when criteria is breached to 16, 63 or 125 however i was wondering there's an code to help calculate only send email if 16 falls within 3 months, 64 falls within 6 months and 125 falls over a year period. how the scoring works basically number of days sickness x number of sets x number of sets.

Comment: "if 16 falls within 3 months" is not clear - do you mean within 3 months of a specific date, withing a 3-moth period, or something else?  Screenshots and a detailed explanation edited into your question will help a lot here.

Comment: Yes sorry what i mean is if it is 16 within 3 months from on the actual date =today() in the last 3 months =today()-90 something to check for last 3 months. how do i upload a screenshot in here? is there away  to upload image or sample book in here?

Comment: There is an "image" button on the toolbar of the edit section.  There's no way we can know how to measure when an absence occurred without knowing more about how your data is laid out.

Comment: hi have just posted the screenshot of sample in the answer i hope i have done it correctly.

Comment: You can *edit your question* to add the screenshot.  In any case, what you're asking for is lot more complex than your original question suggested- you'd need to find some way to loop backwards over the cells from the current date and count the "S" in the time periods of interest (assuming you were far enough into the year to be able to go that far back).  Why not see if you can figure it out, then post back with code if you run into problems?

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for your quick response. thats i am really struggling

Comment: is there no away to compare between two dates in cell e.g. cell A1 has got past date and cell A2 has got present date and then compare against the target of either 16 for example if it within that dare range? many thanks

Comment: something along with this line?                                                                                     
                  If .Value > 15 = Now() <> Sheets("2021").Range("AI30").Value Then

Comment: Yes you can compare two cells but it seemed like you wanted something more complicated than that?

Comment: Hi Tim no just really compare a target which is in B6 cells between two cell dates A1 for past 3 months and A2 for today date, and as along when B6 target is within time frame of that 3 months winnow then send that email. would you you be able to write correct code for this? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please see screenshot of yearly diary

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksRVr.jpg)